# How to change MAC of wlan0?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Can anybody tell me the way to change MAC of `wlan0`?

I have tried `macchanger` commands but nothing works (Ubuntu 12.10-Broadcom Network Adapter).

This is what I am getting:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo ifconfig eth1 down
[sudo] password for shivendra: 
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo service network-manager stop
network-manager stop/waiting
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo macchanger -a eth1
Current MAC: 00:21:00:72:9c:d5 (unknown)
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Too many open files in system
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo macchanger --mac 64:27:37:D8:97:6F eth1
Current MAC: 00:d0:61:9d:bf:a5 (Tremon Enterprises Co., Ltd.)
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Too many open files in system
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo service network-manager start
network-manager start/running, process 2182
shivendra@shivendra-Rev-1-0:~$ sudo macchanger --mac 64:27:37:D8:97:6F eth1
Current MAC: 64:27:37:d8:97:6f (unknown)
ERROR: Can't change MAC: interface up or not permission: Too many open files in system
```

Answer (score 5):

I can tell you a simple way to change the eth1 address without using macchanger.

`sudo ifconfig eth1 down
 sudo ifconfig eth1 hw ether 00:11:22:33:44:55
 sudo ifconfig eth1 up`

Then you're all set with your new mac address.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that modifying **eth1** is what you want to do?? Check your Wifi interface name with ifconfig.
What I would do:

```
sudo service network-manager stop  
sudo macchanger -a wlan0
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: Every other solution i tried was not working for me, but using this i can access the wifi's of others who are protected by mac address. Thanks a ton

Comment: Also, the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm wrong, isn't there a GUI option in Network manager. Click on the network manager icon > select Edit Connections > Edit your ethernet's properties and look out for Clone MAC address field and enter your new MAC.

Answer (score 0):

If you click the networking icon in the Unity 'taskbar' on the top right, then go to **Edit Connections**, you should be able to switch to the **Wireless** tab and open an **Edit** dialog for your connection.

In this edit dialog, the first page has a field to edit your MAC address.  You can type right into the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing `eth1` instead of `wlan0`, change `eth1` to `wlan0` and your MAC-address command will work.

So everywhere there is `eth1` like this:

```
sudo macchanger -a eth1
```

should be like this:

```
sudo machchanger -a wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script that uses macchanger -A to get another MAC address and then updates the necesserary wlan files. [Check it out](http://cyberandspace.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/macbot-0-1-an-interactive-commandline-script-for-macchanger/).

Cheers,

Manuel

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Too many open files in system

suggests that your system reached maximum open files in the operating system.

Run `sysctl kern.num_files` to see how many files are currently open, and `sysctl kern.maxfiles` to check what's the current limit.

To see which files are currently open, run: `lsof | grep -w REG`.

To increase system limit, run:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=4096
```

<sup>Prefix with `sudo` if required or login as `root`.</sup>

For shell limits (such as Bash), use `ulimit` command, e.g.

```
ulimit -Sn 8192 # Increase open files limit.
```